# pySpark, aggregate complex function (difference of consecutive events)

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a DataFrame (`df`) whose columns are `userid` (the user id), `day` (the day).

I'm interested in computing, for every user, the average time interval between each day he/she was active.

For instance, for a given user the DataFrame may look something like this

```
userid       day      
1          2016-09-18        
1          2016-09-20
1          2016-09-25
```

If the DataFrame is a Pandas DataFrame, I could compute the quantity I'm interested in like this

```
import numpy as np
np.mean(np.diff(df[df.userid==1].day))
```

However, this is quite inefficient since I have millions of users in the DataFrame, but I believe it can be done this way

```
df.groupby("userid").agg({"day": lambda x: np.mean(np.diff(x))})
```

The first problem is that I'm not sure this works fine because the dates would need to be sorted before applying `np.mean(np.diff(x))`.

The second question, instead, is that this is inefficient because I can only do that when converting the DataFrame to a Pandas DataFrame.

Is there a way of doing the exact same thing with pySpark?

Answer (score 3):

Window functions come to rescue. Some imports:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, datediff, lag
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
```

window definition

```
w = Window().partitionBy("userid").orderBy("day")
```

and query

```
(df
    .withColumn("diff", datediff(lag("day", 1).over(w), "day"))
    .groupBy("userid")
    .mean("diff"))
```